# use of sed substitute in shell script doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, .htaccess, shell, sed

I have made an install script which basically inserts some **RewriteRule** right after **RewriteEngine On** line by using `sed` inside a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

REWRITE_RULE="RewriteRule \^catalog\/category\/view\/id\/([0-9]+)$ http:\/\/localhost\/app\/#?c=$1 [NE,L,R=301]"
FILE_PATH=".htaccess"

sed -i "s/RewriteEngine on/RewriteEngine on\n\n$REWRITE_RULE/g" $FILE_PATH
```

it does nothing but gives some error like

> : No such file or directory

I tried same commands in shell and it worked without any issues and updated my **.htaccess** file

I am new to shell scripting so don't know the difference of using same command through shell and through script.. please guide

Comment: `.htaccess` is a relevant path you need absolute paths i beleive

Comment: Thanks @Babbleshack for your quick response, actually it works fine in shell also when I use relative path for another script which is for `cp` it works flawlessly

Comment: am sorry above my expertise xD, but i beleive if you call the scripts from a higher up dir then their target dirs, the script would work. If the targets arent in any sub-dirs of the script then the script wont find its target.
I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that your script contains carriage returns due to being saved with DOS end-of-line characters. Use `tr -d '\r' <brokenscript  >fixedscript` to fix your script.

Here's a copy of a session with the problem reproduced and fixed:

```
$ cat file
var=foo

$ cat myscript
sed -i s/foo/bar/ file

$ bash myscript
: No such file or directory

$ shellcheck myscript

In myscript line 1:
sed -i s/foo/bar/ file
                      ^-- SC1017: Literal carriage return. Run script through tr -d '\r' .

$ tr -d '\r' < myscript > fixedscript

$ bash fixedscript

$ cat file
var=bar

$
```

Answer (score 2):

The script itself is fine. Are you sure that the lines posted above are *exactly* as you took them from your script?

The error message indicates that you provided an empty name as the filename, thus I suggest you put a

```
echo "FILE_PATH: $FILE_PATH"
```

directly before your `sed` command in order to check whether the variable is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried this as well and it is echoing `FILE_PATH: .htaccess` but the command isn't working. I tried the other way `sed "s/old/new/g" oldfile > newfile` and it worked, but I don't want to create a new file... I want changes in-place